# Kubuntu broken after update

Tags: updates, kubuntu, kde, kde4

I have Kubuntu 14.04 (3.13.0-66-generic) and after a recent update I get some serious issues in my system. Is a very weird behavior and I can't really get ahead of it... I wonder if it happened to someone else and how to solve it, this is how I reproduce it:

- Start the system;
- Open something like the System Preferences, everything look normal;
- Open Android Studio;
- Open something alse like KCalc or and image, and everythig look weird like this: 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugBGl.jpg 
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BELkG.jpg

So to recap, the apps that I open BEFORE opening Android Studio look fine (even after I open Android Studio), and the apps that I open AFTER Android Studio look weird (even after I close Android Studio). This is affecting mosto of the apps but not all, for example Sublime Text 2 or Chrome have no problem.

I really have no idea what is wrong, or why Android Studio is starting the weird behavior. But the problem starter after one of this updates (more likely the last one):

```
Start-Date: 2015-10-23  09:39:03
Commandline: apt-get upgrade                                                                                                                                                                    
Upgrade: python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16), oxideqt-codecs-extra:amd64 (1.9.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1), python3.4:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (46.0.2490.71-1, 46.0.2490.80-1), python-urllib3:amd64 (1.7.1-1ubuntu3, 1.7.1-1ubuntu4), python3.4-minimal:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3), tzdata-java:amd64 (2015f-0ubuntu0.14.04, 2015g-0ubuntu0.14.04), libpython3.4-stdlib:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3), libpython3.4:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3), libpython3.4-minimal:amd64 (3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.1, 3.4.3-1ubuntu1~14.04.3), apport-kde:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16), apport:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16), python3-apport:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.15, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16), tzdata:amd64 (2015f-0ubuntu0.14.04, 2015g-0ubuntu0.14.04), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (3.13.0-65.106, 3.13.0-66.108)
End-Date: 2015-10-23  09:39:24

Start-Date: 2015-10-23  09:40:55
Install: linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-66.108, automatic), linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-66.108, automatic), linux-headers-3.13.0-66:amd64 (3.13.0-66.108, automatic), linux-headers-3.13.0-66-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-66.108, automatic), linux-signed-image-3.13.0-66-generic:amd64 (3.13.0-66.108, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.65.71, 3.13.0.66.72), linux-signed-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.65.71, 3.13.0.66.72), linux-signed-image-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.65.71, 3.13.0.66.72), linux-image-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.65.71, 3.13.0.66.72), linux-generic:amd64 (3.13.0.65.71, 3.13.0.66.72)
End-Date: 2015-10-23  09:42:32

Start-Date: 2015-10-28  09:46:01
Install: libsctp1:amd64 (1.0.15+dfsg-1, automatic), lksctp-tools:amd64 (1.0.15+dfsg-1, automatic)
Upgrade: python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.18), mysql-server-core-5.5:amd64 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2), mysql-client-core-5.5:amd64 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2), openjdk-7-jdk:amd64 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1, 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1), openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1, 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1), mysql-common:amd64 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2), apport-kde:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.18), libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2), libmysqlclient18:i386 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2), openjdk-7-jre:amd64 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1, 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1), apport-gtk:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.18), apport:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.18), icedtea-7-jre-jamvm:amd64 (7u79-2.5.6-0ubuntu1.14.04.1, 7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1), python3-apport:amd64 (2.14.1-0ubuntu3.16, 2.14.1-0ubuntu3.18), ntpdate:amd64 (4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.04.3, 4.2.6.p5+dfsg-3ubuntu2.14.04.5)
End-Date: 2015-10-28  09:46:15
```

Any clue?

---

Update:

I believe the problem could be in openjdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was in "openjdk", I installed oracle-java following this tutorial and now everything seens to be working fine...
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get

Answer (score 1):

I experience the same issue.
Finally I found the bug report on launchpad which seems to track this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1512760